# How to segment license plate character?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am facing a problem in segmenting characters from a license plate image.

I have applied following method to extract license plate characters:

1. Rgb2gray.
2. Canny edge detection and dilation.
3. Mark and filter areas.
4. Extract a single characters image.

The results are attached.

[image]

On the first column work well.

At the second column there is a Chinese plate, and it is difficult to correctly identify every character.

At the third column there is another plate, which it was rotated through the hough transform because it was from another angle, however, it cannot detect any character.

I'm working [on Colab.](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1p5Fvip6sdyV-qkpwDMXFZLYeVc64vQFP?usp=sharing) using opencv mostly.

What can I improve? any advice?

These are the image im working [at this link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1I0aDv8BoqmZvWXgjD3xlThTzUaLlWDXs)

Comment: The perspective on the third column is highly distorted - what is your solution to try and rectify it?

Comment: what do you recommend?

Comment: Apply a [4 Point Perspective rectification](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/08/25/4-point-opencv-getperspective-transform-example/).